# fluentd: ignore_repeated_log_interval and ignore_same_log_interval

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, td-agent

Trying to suppress same logs in fluentd by using fluentd system directives  ignore_repeated_log_interval and ignore_same_log_interval, but no working action has been observed

MY fluentd.conf

```html
## conf file
<match fluent.**>
      @type null
</match>
<system>
  log_level info
  ignore_repeated_log_interval 5s
  ignore_same_log_interval 5s
  suppress_repeated_stacktrace true
</system>
<source>
  @type tail
  read_from_head true
  #path /home/nikhil.nayak/ngp/dlog2.txt
  path /home/nikhil.nayak/ngp/log.txt
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/fluentd-docker.pos
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  format none
  tag docker.*
</source>
<match **>
  @type elasticsearch
  @id out_es
  @log_level info
  include_tag_key true
  logstash_format true
  host 
  port 9600
  flush_interval 5s
  type_name "_doc"
  logstash_prefix logstash
  logstash_format true
  index_name logstash
 <buffer>
   flush_thread_count 8
   flush_interval 5s
   chunk_limit_size 2M
   queue_limit_length 32
   retry_max_interval 30
   retry_forever true
 </buffer>
</match>
#<match **>
 #@type stdout
#</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

section parameters concerns to the Fluentd logging mechanism them self. Not for the data pipelines from a source.